# Why isn't this Yahoo Pipe outputting items?

Tags: html, rss, yahoo-pipes

I have a [Yahoo! Pipe](http://pipes.yahoo.com/mrclay/crockford_blog) that attempts to transform an [HTML page](http://profiles.yahoo.com/blog/GSBHPXZFNRM2QRAP3PXNGFMFVU) into RSS, but the resulting [feed](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=yqqmj3xN3hGsftD__w6H4A&_render=rss) contains no items. For each entry I've parsed these elements:

- link (permalink)
- title (HTML title)
- description (HTML entry)
- guid (segment of the permalink)

Various tutorials led me to add these:

- dc:creator ("Doug")
- y:id.value (permalink)
- y:published (w/ date attributes generated from text like "3 days ago")

If you [edit source](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.edit?_id=yqqmj3xN3hGsftD__w6H4A) and highlight Pipe Output, the debugger shows 5 entries with these elements/attributes intact.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

That is vexing! By tweaking it a bit to do "emit results" in the "Loop" operator box I managed to get a feed with 5 items, but it only contained the item.guid for some reason.

Your feed is valid though (not that hard considering there's no elements) according to http://feedvalidator.org.

I tried removing some of your components but my changes did not help.

By the way, crazy nuts that they kill Yahoo360 blogs in favor of the feedless Yahoo Profile blogs. Oh, and I like Douglas Crockford too. :-)